# Logout from multiple systems in SSO (Single Sign On)

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I am implementing SSO for our systems in order to centralize the user authentication and authorization, in which we will have a SSO-server (User and Session Manager) where the user logs in using his/her credentials and then will be able to access all other associated systems.

The implementation of SSO:

1. First the user will get the session (access token + refresh token)
   and they will be stored in the client side.
2. If he redirects
   to the other systems a (single use token) will be generate by SSO
   server for that system
3. And up on the system loading the (single use
   token) will be exchanged with a pair of access-token and refresh
   token and they will be stored in the client side of that particular
   system
4. And on each server request the session (access token +
   refresh token) will be sent through request header so that the
   system's server could request this user's authorization from SSO
   server.

Access token has less expiry time than refresh token and it's not stored in SSO server and only it's signature is checked for authorization but the refresh token is stored so that we could revoke it later if needed.
(due to the huge amount authorization requests that we will have later on I did not want to stored the access token.)

The problem is that if a user wants to logout, all his/her access tokens should be expired but they are not stored in database and only in client side for each system and I can only revoke the refresh token so the token remains valid until it's expiry time passes and till then it can be used and it means the user is still login.

I use JWT for the token generation and verificaiton.

This is my first question in here I hope I have explained the problem properly.
And I will be waiting for your kind responses.

Comment: Where are you storing the access tokens in the clientside. Cookie or localstorage?

Comment: @himank localstorage

Answer (score 0):

Preferably use a cookie to store your tokens. When the user has logged out. Simply clear the cookie and return. Now the user does not have the access token and won't be authenticated.

Note: Make sure to make a secure cookie.

Comment: But how do I access the other domains cookie?

Comment: Do you want, logout of all the systems, if anybody logs out of the sso server app?